# Gradle/Maven project fork provides original artifact (only download fork)

Tags: maven, gradle

**Description**

I have forked another project and uploaded it to my own maven repository. The dependency graph, however, pulls the original project too, meaning I two versions of the projects. The compilation works fine in command-line but not in eclipse as it reads the original project's jar first and then skips my forked project.

**Dependency graph**

```
+--- com.spiddekauga.gdx:gdx-spiddekauga (fork)
+--- com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d
|    \--- com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx (original)
```

**What I've tried**

First I tried using the original name of `com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx` but the project was downloaded from the original maven repository instead of mine even if my maven repository is listed before.

*build.gradle*

```
allprojects {
    ...
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://maven.MY-DOMAIN.org/" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" } 
    }
    ... 
}
```

Another thing I've search for is to make `com.spiddekauga.gdx:gdx-spiddekauga` provide `com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx` so that it doesn't have to be downloaded, but I haven't found a way to do this in neither in gradle or maven.

**Questions**

1. How can I solve so that only my forked project is pulled? Either by a) renaming to `com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx` so it searches my maven repository first; or b) by excluding the dependency `com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx`.
2. *[minor question]* Is it possible to set that a maven project provides another artifact? E.g. like this:

*pom.xml*

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.spiddekauga.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-spiddekauga</artifactId>

    <provides>
        <project>
            <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdx</gdx>
        </project>
    </provides>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forking the project does not change the project coordinates (`groupId`, `projectId` and `version`) in the `pom`or gradle files.  You would need to search and replace all of them for it to work.

Also the dependencies that you are referring to are available in [mavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgdx-box2d), which is the first in the repositories list.

Comment: That's true, although I used the snapshot version which wasn't there. I've moved down mavenCentral and it still fetches from that project.

One thing that is noteworthy. I've only forked gdx (and not gdx-box2d). Also gdx-sqlite (not visible) is another project that is dependent on gdx. I will test to remove the gdx-box2d and see which version gdx-sqlite pulls. If it pulls the original that means I have to fork every project that uses gdx (that I use).

Comment: As gdx-box2d and gdx both are modules of a larger 'gdx' project gdx-box2d pulls the original gdx. Which means I 'only' have to deploy all main gdx modules.

I.e. when forking I have to use the same groupId because if I use people's independent projects that depend on gdx they will pull the original and not my version.